# ARWorldTrackingConfiguration vs ARImageTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to make an app with ARKit in iOS swift where a QR code can be detected and then I can constantly measure the 3D position between the detected QR code and the camera, even when the QR code leaves the screen Is ARWorldTrackingConfiguration or ARImageTrackingConfiguration better suited to this? Can ARImageTrackingConfiguration keep track if image anchors even when the reference image leaves the screen or is ARWorldTrackingConfiguration better for this? I should also mention that the reference image will stay static and unmoving. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`, you can keep track of image anchors (`ARImageAnchor`) even when the reference image leaves the screen. `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` is standalone, meaning that it does not run world tracking and operates separately.

On the other hand, `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` tracks orientation and position with 6DOF, allows augmentation within the physical environment, and creates a world map. Therefore, if you plan to incorporate these features in the future, you may consider using it.

I recommend watching this video for more detail: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/610/